# Default PATH system variable for Windows?

Tags: windows, default, system-variable

I've accidentally messed up the `PATH` variable in Windows and I'm wondering if anyone could provide the default for me.

Comment: See http://superuser.com/a/113656 for recovering the last good known configuration

Comment: see same question on superuser:

[what-is-the-default-path-environment-variable-setting-on-fresh-install-of-windows](https://superuser.com/questions/124239/what-is-the-default-path-environment-variable-setting-on-fresh-install-of-window)

Comment: I have just created a new user account and its user path only contained `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps`. (I'm running windows 11)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My freshly installed Windows 8.1 has the following value in `PATH`:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
```

Comment: I had been using this solution for approximately two weeks with a majority of command line utilities still not working. Turns out that the `PATH=` part is **NOT** part of the path. If anyone else tries this solution by pasting it into your environment variable window (not command line) then you'll need to remove it.

Comment: @Winter That's a good point, I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
%JAVA_HOME%\bin;C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin;%ANT_HOME\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;C:\Oracle\bin;C:\Informatica\9.1.0\DataTransformation\bin;C:\Informatica\9.1.0\clients\tools\datadirect;C:\Informatica\9.1.0\clients\DeveloperClient\bin;C:\Informatica\9.1.0\clients\java\jre\bin\server;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Lenovo;C:\Program Files (x86)\Perforce;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Services\IPT\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Lenovo\Access Connections\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd
```

This is mine, I think you modify it based on the software you installed.

Comment: Always interesting to see what software screws up the PATH.  That machine isn't controlled by the operating system, it's pwned by Ellison.