# Overwrite path content on Windows 8.1 - Environment Variables

Tags: mysql, windows, path, environment-variables, mysql-workbench

I accidentally overwrote the path content at the environment variables a few days ago. How can i restore it? Anyone has the default path for windows 8.1 (x64)?

Btw, i cant use MySQL workbench because of this. it shows me an error that says:

> RuntimeError: Unable to execute command chcp. Please make sure that the C:\Windows\System32 directory  is in your PATH environment variable.

an then says this:

> An error occurred while the application  executed  the given startup action. the returned error is: error calling Python module function wbAdmin.openAdminSection See also the output window.

Help me please! :-(

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your Windows 8.1 PATH, see the [related StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19779856/default-path-system-variable-for-windows). Regarding MySQL PATH settings, see [the related MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-installation-windows-path.html). I also have "C:\Python33\" as used by the related MySQL Utilities, but your setup might differ.